# Get reference to AudioSource intantiatied via AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint()

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[`AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint()`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint.html) adds an `AudioSource` component to the current gameObject that the monobehaviour is attached to. However, for some reason, it has a void return type rather than returning a reference to the `AudioSorce` component. Very strange!

Is there any way to *efficiently* get a reference to the created `AudioSource` component so that parameters such as pitch and volume can be changed?

Edit: I have since found [this](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/316575/adjust-properties-of-audiosource-created-with-play.html) on answers.unity which answers this question perfectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`AudioSource.PlayOneShot()` does **NOT** add an `audioSource` component to the current **gameObject**. It plays the sound/audioClip provided in the parameter.

```
AudioSource myAudio;
myAudio = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
myAudio.pitch = 1f;
myAudio.volume = 1f;
myAudio.PlayOneShot(myAudio.clip);
```

**EDIT**:

Since your question is edited and `PlayOneShot()` is changed to `PlayClipAtPoint()`, `PlayClipAtPoint` is a static function. It creates an `AudioSource`, plays the sound, then destroys the `AudioSource`.

It does **NOT** add the `AudioSource` to the **current** Object. It just creates each `AudioSource` as a **parent** GameObject in the scene. It's for playing  short sounds and you should not try to get the reference because it does not return one and you may end up getting another reference in the scene.

You can't change the `pitch` but you **can** change the `volume` by supplying the **third** parameter.

```
AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint(myAudio.clip, this.transform.position, 1);
```

Comment: Shoot. I meant to say AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint(). I will edit the question.

Comment: looking back over the docs for PlayClipAtPoint() though, I'm assuming that it also doesn't add the AudioSource to the current gameObject?

Comment: @gjttt1 Modified thee question again to answer your question in the comment.